# Metamask Unable to send transactions to Ethereum private network

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, metamask

I'm using Metamask.io extension on Google Chrome.
Correctly connected Metamask.io to Private network hosted on AWS EC2 instance using the socket address (IP:port number).
Basic Contract has been deployed on the blockchain using Remix IDE for solidity programming. I am able to fetch the information (getInstructor function). However, unable to set the new instructor information.

Steps -

1. On Remix IDE, I call the function.
2. It opens the Metamask pop-up and I use the default gas price.
3. Transaction never gets executed.

On the ethereum private blockchain node, I tried to find pending transactions and there wasn't any.
As shown by,

```
> eth.pendingTransactions
[]
```

However upon trying this,

```
web3.eth.getBlock("pending")
{
  difficulty: 25082169,
  extraData: "0xd583010701846765746885676f312e39856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 4712388,
  gasUsed: 0,
  hash: null,
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: null,
  mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: null,
  number: 1557557,
  parentHash: "0xf84ce5ff7845f399eb698bfc33abeb24a8e459096d7ad9c097de3eb6130a6360",
  receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 537,
  stateRoot: "0x017184c9d24daab688c39468af064cd3ab748f5adc9c5b1fd3c5bcc2f3a318a0",
  timestamp: 1523753000,
  totalDifficulty: 0,
  transactions: [],
  transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  uncles: []
}
```

Few days back I was able to perform this basic transaction but now I am not. Unable to understand what's the issue.

Possible errors -

According to these discussions

[miner nodes](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3694%20%22miner%20nodes) and 
[transaction not being sent](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2769), I tried creating another personal account and letting it mine (that failed).

Comment: Are you mining in your node? ie did you run `mine.start(1)` or something similar. From your pending block it has number 1557557, which is quite high for a private testnet, what does `eth.blockNumber` returns? Are you sure you are connecting to the correct network.

Comment: I have been mining in my node. Yes, I am absolutely sure I have connected to the correct network (my private test network with corresponding IP:Port). Here's blocknumber info - 
 `> eth.blockNumber`
`1558456`

Answer (score 2):

The "usual" setup for development is not to connect Metamask to your AWS node because you don't want to expose APIs to that node. I'm guessing you're using POA right ?

**Just get a local node running on your computer and connect metamask to localhost.**

By default the node will only accept connections from localhost. You can change this to accept connections from anyone with: --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0".

Please note that anytime a private key is unlocked, anyone on the Internet can use this key by querying your rpc server and send transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're having this problem:
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1722

Try setting `chainId` and `networkId` to the same value, to help MetaMask stay EIP-155 compliant.

A guide to using a custom node with MetaMask is here:
https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/USERS.md#using-a-local-node

Comment: The fact that I was able to send transactions previously helps me to say that most probably I dont have any issues with MetaMask staying EIP-155 compliant (since if it that was the case I would not have been able to send transactions previously). I have set networkId to a particular value while spinning the private network and it looks correct. I think the problem I'm facing is something to do with the fact that currently it is just me who is in the network for test purposes and have been trying lot of transactions. Hence now speed has become an issue. Not sure if I am 100% right. But guess.

Comment: I dont have EIP155 block set in my custom-genesis.json besides my network id is 1205 set during creation of multi-user geth service which is different from chainId = 0 setup in genesis.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Basically my smart contract didn't have "payable" in the function where you send Ethereum. You're saying that everything works correctly, you can fetch, metamask opens but doesn't send Ethereum. 
Try to add "payable" and let me know if that worked so I know to look more deep into your problem.